# Android: Not able to place an matrix imageview at the center of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview, android-framelayout

I am working on Image Zooming. Everything is fine.I am trying to display an matrix image at the center of the layout. But I am not able to do it.

My xml is:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/root1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/root"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```

And I've used this solution from stack overflow but I am not getting center placed image. Image is aligning top left of the screen. Please help me.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    screenWidth = rel.getWidth();
    screenHeight = rel.getHeight();

    Log.e("",
            "Image Width : " + image.getWidth() + "  >  "
                    + image.getHeight());
    Log.e("", "screen Width : " + screenWidth + "  >  " + screenHeight);
    Matrix matrix = image.getImageMatrix();
    RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight());
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    matrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    image.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    image.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using a `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: I've used Relative layout also but No result.@XaverKapeller

Comment: And the problem is not the position of the `ImageView` but its size. You have set its height and width to `match_parent` which makes the `ImageView` as big as the layout containing it. Try `wrap_content` instead.

Comment: Here I am using this for Zoom. If I set wrapcontent the width and height will be fixed and the image will be scaled(Zoomed) in that area only. Above is my requirement in that I want to place the Image at the center of the screen.@XaverKapeller

Comment: In that case the problem is that your matrix does not place the transformed image in the center of the `ImageView`. You need to modify your matrix and not your layout. Add the appropriate translations to place the image in the center of the `ImageView`.

Comment: In onwindowsfocuschanged method I've done that. But it is not working. Can you tell me how to modify the matrix to place the image in the center of the ImageView.@XaverKapeller

Comment: Judging from your code it should work. the `setRectToRect()` call combined with `Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER` should center the image inside your `ImageView`. I suggest you debug the method and check if all the values like `screenWidth`, `screenHeight`, `image.getWidth()`, `image.getHeight()` etc are correct. There might be some timing issues.

Comment: Ok now I understand what you have suggested. thanku@XaverKapeller

Answer (score 2):

Here I've to use drawable(which is set to imageview) intrinsic width and height as a screenWidth and screenHeight

Here is my solution:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    float imageWidth = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    float imageHeight = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
    RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageView.getWidth(),
            imageView.getHeight());
    Matrix matrix = imageView.getMatrix();
    matrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    imageView.invalidate();

}
```